# Put a table* at the bottom of a page?

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, starred-version

In a two column document in LaTeX, is there any way to put a `table*` (a `table` spanning both columns) at the bottom of the page?  The obvious doesn't work:

```
\begin{table*}[b]   % b!, hb, hb!, etc. doesn't work either
   %... a wide table
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

(I just learned about this recently:) This can be solved by loading the [`stfloats`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stfloats) package and specifying a figure placement of `[bp]` as usual. (The `p` should always be included in case the bottom placement can never be achieved.)

Comment: it didn't work for me:/

Comment: I assumed it would be the same to use `[hbtp]`, but that was not the case. I really had to change the placement to `[bp]` for the tamble to be placed on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Apparently this works also for **top** placement via `[tp]` or maybe `[tp!]`.

Answer (score 21):

Use

```
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
```

and thereof the command

```
\begin{table*}[!b]
```

This works better than `stfloats`, as `stfloats` jumbles up some figures occationally

Comment: new person question: how do I install a LaTeX package?

Comment: looking for an existing question - it's not clear which one I want https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=install%20package

Comment: this might be the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/how-do-i-install-ctan-packages-on-mac-os-with-texshop

Comment: In my case `dblfloatfix` did not work, but `stfloats` did

Comment: I can confirm that `dblfloatfix` no longer appears to work, whereas `stfloats` does.

Comment: Neither worked for me, both still send the image to the bottom of the document.

Comment: I would suggest trying one or the other of the two solutions, one worked for me.