# How do I install CTAN packages on Mac OS with TexShop?

Tags: packages, installing, texshop

I run [TexShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop) on my Mac OS 10.6.

I'd like to install new packages like this: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/

How do I install it? I've downloaded the zip file.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I will assume you are using MacTeX (The Mac specific distribution of TeXLive)

Before answering your question, the listings package you mention is part of the TeXLive distribution. You don't actually have to install it, it is already there. Just include the line

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

in your preamble.

If you have to install a package, there are several quick ways to install a package.

1. For packages found on CTAN: use the [TeX Live Utility](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/) found in your `/Applications/TeX` folder.
   This application can keep all of your TeX packages up to date.
2. Place the relevant files in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`.
   TeX will find them.
3. Enter `tlmgr install *packagename*` in the Terminal.pp window

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My Tex Live Utility crashed on launch no matter how many times I tried. I went with your second option and it worked really well! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Frédéric: Maybe you could reorder your question so that the “you already have this package installed” information is at the top. Past experience has shown that unnecessary manual installation of packages leads to all kind of trouble. People coming here from google searches might only read the first part of your post and run into trouble. (As a side remark, greetings generally not used on this site, as we want to keep the focus on the actual content.)

Comment: @the_great_monkey: As Frédéric said, `listings` should be part of your default TeX Live installation, so there should be no need to install it manually.

Comment: @Carambir: Thanks for the suggestions. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Caramdir Ah... that's right. I tried using lstlistings before and I got the message "can not find lstlistings.sty" and then I just realised that I should have used listings! Thanks

Comment: @Frédéric: Great!

Comment: What about packages that are in CTAN but are **not** on the TeX Live distribution? I'm trying to install Emerald which is on CTAN but not on TeX Live.

Comment: Upvoted both question and answer, i think this is pretty essential stuff to know for (Mac)Tex beginners :)

Comment: texmf not found