# How can I install uarial.sty on a mac?

Tags: packages, installing, texshop

I'm using TexShop (2.43 on 10.6) to manage LaTeX, but have the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'uarial.sty' not found.
```

I tried to use the approach in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/how-do-i-install-ctan-packages-on-mac-os-with-texshop) with

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

But apparently, uarial.sty isn't already installed.  It is definitely a [CTAN package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-arial), and I don't see any relevant packages in TeX Live's download list.  What package should I look for in the download list, as the downloads are taking forever?  Or is there some other way I should be using?

I attempted to install the non-free fonts.  To do so, I've done this:

1. Downloaded install-getnonfreefonts from the link @MarcoDaniel provided.
2. created the following script to avoid having to edit my own path:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> #script to run the font installer once it's in the directory
>     export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH
>
> exec texlua ~/Downloads/install-getnonfreefonts

3. Ran that script as sudo, got this output:

```
    Detected System: x86_64-darwin
    Detected Installation: /usr/local/texlive/2010
    Installing texmf/scripts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl ...          [done]
    Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.1 ...                      [done]
    Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts-sys.1 ...                  [done]
    Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...               [done]
    Installing texmf/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts-sys.man1.pdf ...           [done]
    md5sum: cdc91dd4b6bea936a013a16836421a0b getnonfreefonts.pl ...            [ok]
    md5sum: f850d910dd96ee27cecdb3772047d247 getnonfreefonts.1 ...             [ok]
    md5sum: fb2b0f7699db8e627d4e26b730e94928 getnonfreefonts-sys.1 ...         [ok]
    md5sum: 415b51f7c80a4abe8d0a667a04c9d525 getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...      [ok]
    Fixing File Permissions ...                                              [done]
    Creating symlinks in 'bin/universal-darwin' ...                          [done]
    Creating symlinks in 'bin/x86_64-darwin' ...                             [done]
    texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/ls-R... 
    texhash: Done.
```

4. Restarted TeXShip
5. Rebuilt the file, no joy.

Answer (score 10):

The font can be easily installed via the script `getnonfreefonts`. It is available at tug.org:

[TUG getnonfreefonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/)

---

**EDIT:** I tried the installation of [getnonfreefonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) on my Mac. In the follwoing explaniation I will try to explain my steps. 
First I have the following machine:

- iMac 27"
- Installed updated MacTeX 2011

Now the steps.

1. I downloaded the [installation script](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts).
2. Open the terminal and go to the folder *Download*

   `cd Download`
3. Run the installation:

   `sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts`
4. The installation finished and the scipts with their execute files `getnonefreefonts` and `getnonfreefonts-sys` are now located at

   `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin/`
5. Now you can run the script

   `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a`

Comment: Does this require that '/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin
' be on the path?  I've been avoiding modifying my path, as path pollution tends to make my life heinous.

Comment: This did not work.  See the edits on my question.

Comment: @mmr: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: With current `getnonfreefonts` you need `getnonfreefonts --sys -a` instead of `getnonfreefonts-sys -a`!

Answer (score 6):

If you can't use the `getnonfreefonts` script for some reason, you'll need to copy the relevant files yourself. I suggest you install them in your LOCALTEXMF directory tree. You'll need to have root or sudo privileges.

- Download `arial.zip` from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial/ to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. (**Update**, 2011/11/012: this zip file used to be called "ua1.zip", but at some point the file name appears to have been changed to "arial.zip".)
- Uncompress the zip file. Various files will be copied into sub- and subsub-directories below the `doc`, `dvips`, `fonts`, and `tex` directories (including `uarial.sty` to `tex/latex/ua1` and `ua1.map` to `fonts/map/dvips/ua1`).
- Run `sudo -H mktexlsr`.
- Run the command `sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=ua1.map`. (Update, 2012/11/02: The map file is still called "ua1.map" even though the name of the zip file has changed to arial.zip -- see above.)
- Run `sudo -H mktexlsr` again.

Happy TeXing!

Comment: This approach yields the error, @Mico: `!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ua1b8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading`.  I had to run `sudo ~/Downloads/updmap-sys.sh --enable Map=ua1.map --syncwithtrees`, because there were some other files missing.  Is my installation just hosed at this point?

Comment: At this point, I honestly can't tell. There's a separate issue: your TeX distribution is mildly obsolete. Have you considered installing MacTeX 2011?

Comment: @mmr pdflatex complains that it can't open ua1b8a.pfb. So did you install the fonts (they are in the same folder as ua1.zip and should go to fonts/type1/arial)?

Comment: @Mico-- I thought I had the most recent non-Lion build.  I'll check out the new hotness... although this is due today at 5, so workarounds will be made instead, I think.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer-- I followed Mico's advice above, with the syncwithtrees extra switch.  Is there further work to be done to install the font?

Comment: @mmr: If a workaround is all you need/want for today, why don't you use the Helvetica font (nearly indistinguishable from Arial, or vice versa, for most readers)? Try something like `\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}`.

Comment: @Mico-- my collaborator is insisting on Arial for an NIH submission, to keep everything within page and spacing limits.

Comment: @mmr Arial and Helvetica have exactly the same glyph dimensions. (This is not by accident, of course.) Hence switching between the two will have no effect on the constraints you mention. ;-)

Comment: Unless I'm woefully mistaken, the file "ua1.zip" seems no longer to be present at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial/  ... where to find this manually?

Comment: @TeXnewbie -- I would appear that the file that used to be called "ua1.zip" is now called "arial.zip". When you click on the "download zip file" link, you'll get "arial.zip". From a quick inspection of its contents, it looks like it has the same contents as the old "ua1.zip" file had.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Mico. Actually, ua1.zip is a proper subset of arial.zip, and although the files they have in common are all identical, there are more than 20 (of 55) additional files in arial.zip, including afm, pfm, pfb files and ua1fnst.zip, and yet the README (present only in arial.zip) still refers to ua1.zip. What's up with that? uarial.sty is apparently the same version in both zip files. What is the purpose of the new information present in arial.zip that's not present in ua1.zip? Just curious now as your tip has mostly solved my problem.

Comment: Installing via `getnonfreefonts` and trying to use Arial would not work for me (font expansion errors) until I tried `sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=ua1.map` as suggested here. This is on a Linux box, not Mac. Thanks for the hint!