# Where would I find ua1.zip?

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, texshop

I'm using TeXShop Version 2.47, and I know from having written a twenty page document last year using apa6e (which I typeset again with no problem today) that this system is in a functional state.

However, I'd now like to use uarial.sty in a similar document, and for some reason, I'm not able to do so.

I found [this excellent question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/how-can-i-install-uarial-sty-on-a-mac) yesterday.

Although I *was* able to follow the instructions in the first answer (using `getnonfreefonts`), for some reason, my TeXLive system (2011 running in OS 10.6) still cannot use uarial.sty. I get the standard error message `latex error uarial.sty not found`. I even ran `texhash` after running `getnonfreefonts-sys -a` and still my system is not finding it.

I know my system is out of date, and I think I may have a partial TL2012 installation installed alongside my 2011 system, and that's probably related to the reason that `getnonfreefonts` is not working for me. However, with a deadline approaching and a functional system in place, I'm loathe to attempt a complete upgrade before the end of the semester.

I know the directories of my two TeXLive systems are as follows:

`/usr/local/texlive/2011/` (2011)
`/opt/local/share/` (2012)

And I found where `getnonfreefonts` put uarial.sty is in:

`/opt/local/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/ua1`

But I need for it to be put into my `/usr/local/texlive/2011/` root in order for TeXShop to see it. So I tried a manual copy of the directory `/opt/local/share/texmf-local/tex/latex/ua1` to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/` but I think I missed some accessory files (ua1.map et. al.?) in doing this which is why (although TeXShop did notice the uarial.sty file) that created a whole host of other problems for me.

So I'm looking for the whole `ua1.zip` file so I can do as suggested in the second answer, but it's apparently no longer to be found at the URL listed in the [second answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/how-can-i-install-uarial-sty-on-a-mac).

Anyone know how I can download ua1.zip by itself so I can manually get the .sty file and all of its accessories into my 2011 root? Thanks in advance.

---

### Update

I should've added that I did google this question and aside from the URL mentioned in the second answer, found no hits, thus the seemingly trivial question.

I also downloaded arial.zip at that same URL and looked inside arial.zip for ua1.zip ([that I think was previously to be found in arial.zip](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1546988.html) and that is even mentioned in the README for arial.zip), but as of today, the only zip file inside arial.zip is ua1fnst.zip; no ua1.zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it [here](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/text-processing/CTAN/fonts/urw/arial/)  If that's down then you can grab it [here](http://www.smallfiles.org/download/3305/ua1.zip.html).