# Bold font and uarial

Tags: fonts, bold

I found an old closed post related but without a satisfactory answer.

I have to prepare a document with some specific guidelines.
1) Font should be Arial
2) Titles should be 14pt and Bold
3) Rest of document 11pt

The \Large font size I suppose is close enough (would be nice to get it exact though).  However, I am not able to get bold fonts.  Does uarial have this ability?  How about italic style too?

Here is a mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\Large {\textbf{Should be Bold and 14pt}}}
\end{center}

\section{Section Heading}\label{sec:background}
Text here at 11pt \\ 
\emph{italic text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont \textbf{Should be Bold and 14pt}}` works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  When I try that it does not look bold to me.  The font looks a little larger that the \Large too (which is strange, since I thought \Large was like 14.4pt or near that).

Comment: It should be bold (and look very different than a text set simply with `\Large`). The `emph`-text should be slanted. If it doesn't for you you should show your log-file.

Comment: ok..I think my problem is I have not installed these fonts correctly.  I am now trying to figure out how to do that...thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the difference:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont \textbf{Should be Bold and 14pt}}\par
{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont Shouldn't be Bold but 14pt}\par
{\Large Shouldn't be Bold but 14pt}
\end{center}

\section{Section Heading}\label{sec:background}
Text here at 11pt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...I realized my problem was I did not have the fonts installed properly.  I found this thread to help me out and now things work like your example. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/how-can-i-install-uarial-sty-on-a-mac