# insdljs --- TL install and post document expiration popup?

Tags: texlive, ctan, acrotex

I would like to use javascript in my pdflatex documents to test if the document is too old; and if so, put up a popup window reminder to delete the current version and download an updated version from a url.  Of course, this is not really pdf content protection, because it is easy to turn off or remove javascript.  It's intended to be a reminder.

Should be easy, me thinks–insdljs.sty.  I used it a few years ago.

Alas, neither acrotex nor insdljs seem to be part of texlive-2016.  This gives me pause.  It's been years that I have had to download anything from ctan.  Usually, everything that's useful and recommended is already in texlive.  So, now I am wondering – maybe there is a better solution by now?!

I also found some conflicting info here on txsx---does one use the "Tex Live Utility" to download and install ctan packages or not?  [How do I install CTAN packages on Mac OS with TexShop?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/how-do-i-install-ctan-packages-on-mac-os-with-texshop) suggests one can use TLU, which would be nice if this then gains the smarts to update the packages when outdated.  alas, other txsx posts say it only is for packages on texlive, not more generelly on ctan.

advice?

regards,

/iaw

Comment: TeX Live have a policy of not including anything that _absolutely requires_ closed-source software. As such, anything which purely works with Adobe Reader (and thus JavaScript) doesn't go in. This is why the code is on CTAN but not in TL.

Comment: this seems strange.  I think js in pdf is an open spec, just like pdf--both created by adobe.  any viewer can implement it.  tex supports pdf; why not support pdf+js??  so insdljs should not be so bad.  but I get the point.