# how to install picins in MacTeX

Tags: texlive, installing, mactex, picins

How to install picins package on MacTeX (on MacOS Sierra)?
I could not find the package in my TeXLive installation. 
Thx

Comment: Have yout tried it manually with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5085/124842 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12104/124842.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you considered use of [`wrapfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) or [`floatflt`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatflt) instead?  Both are more recent ([`picins`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins) seems to pre-date LaTeX2e) and available under LPPL so should be available through MacTeX.  Otherwise obtain [`picins`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins) from CTAN using the `sty` file from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/picins).