# prevent page break while returning to twocolumn

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, ieeetran

I'm writing a IEEE conference paper. The format of paper is `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` For inserting a wide image i switched to one column using `\onecolumn` The image took half of my page. After that when I again issued command `\twocolumn` it resulted in page break and the two column contents thereafter are appearing from next page. Can anyone please help me as to what I can do to prevent the page break.

Comment: Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? Use `example-image` (from the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)) for the image...

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol *might* help *if* you do not need any of the features it breaks e.g. single-column floats within the multicolumn environment. http://ctan.org/pkg/adjmulticol is an extension (but I've never used this second package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a wide image that spans both columns at the top of the page, either by using a two column float (`figure*`) or by using the optional argument of `\twocolumn` which specifies a spanning text to be put over the columns, so

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[%
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}}%
]

\loop
\stepcounter{enumi}
\ifnum\value{enumi}<1000
\roman{enumi}
\repeat



\end{document}
```

Comment: There may be some other options, but none of them are particularly elegant.  See [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Answer (score 0):

## Switching from any column to single column

```
\begin{multicols}{1}[{
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
    \caption{<table caption>}
    \centering
    <Your Table Contents>
\end{table*}
}]
\end{multicols}
```

## Switching from any column to double column

```
\begin{multicols}{2}[{
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
    \caption{<table caption>}
    \centering
    <Your Table Contents>
\end{table*}
}]
\end{multicols}
```