# placing the figure at bottom of the page

Tags: floats, positioning

I want to place the column-spanned figure at the bottom of the page  near to the text  but using `\begin{figure*}[b]` goes the figure to the end of the document!! Why?

```
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{fig.eps}
    \caption{Something}
    \label{f1}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: This will depend on the actual text or your document. I think a MWE would help.

Comment: I believe `figure*` means float and then you are trying to force placement with `[b]`.  Try using just `{figure}[b]`.

Comment: @dustin A `figure*` will span both columns in a twocolumn document, so I assume that is what mahmood has. Using `figure` wont help then, as that only uses one column.

Comment: @mahmood `figure*` can only be placed at the top, by default. There is an FAQ about this: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=2colfloat

Comment: there's a totally ugly hack for putting a full-width figure at the bottom of a two-column page, explained in this answer to the question [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/579).