# Placing a wide matrix in a two column paper

Tags: two-column

The terms in the matrix below are actually very wide and it should be inserted in a two column page format, so I would like to put it with the whole width of the page at the end of the page. I was wandering if there is a way to make it as included in the attached image.

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{D} & =\begin{pmatrix}
& a & b & \cdots & c\\
& a & b & \cdots & c\\
&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
& a & b & \cdots & c\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

that is possible, but not on the first page of the article. Insert it like a float without a caption:

```
\documentclass[conference,a5paper,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext2
\begin{figure*}[b]%% over both columns
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{D} & =\begin{pmatrix}
& a & b & \cdots & c\\
& a & b & \cdots & c\\
&\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
& a & b & \cdots & c\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*} 
\end{figure*}

\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

The image shows the bottom of the second page:

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, and this matrix is not included in the first page of the file. However, when I do it like this, the matrix is shifted by two pages. Is there a way to force it to be on the same page ?

Comment: except of the first page, which is not possible (as I already wrote), it should appear on the bottom of the current or the next page. You can try `[!b]` but I suppose that will make no difference.

Comment: if you really need a full-width float at the bottom of the first page, there's a horrible hack described in the edited answer to [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/579)

Comment: I don't need it at the first page, but I wanted it on the same page as I declare it, which doesn't happen by applying this code. I tried [!b], [h] and [H] but it still appears on a new empty page on the middle.

Comment: In general it is always on the same page. But depending to your text it maybe possible that is has to move to the next page. In such a case move the `figure*` environment up or back in your text.

Comment: I tried different settings, I even shortened the matrix such that I am sure it would fit, but it is always placed in the middle of an empty page. I tried \FloatBarrier to force it on a section, however the result was the same

Comment: ou should move the `figure*` environment up in the text to see what happens.

Comment: I moved it everywhere, but still the same result.

Comment: Then I need the complete code to give more help

Comment: yes, I know its hard to determine the problem without the whole code, but thanks for trying.

I found that using your code with repeating \blindtext until the file is more than 2 pages, and then removing the \blinddocument\blinddocument would give the same result as I have in my document.

do u know why does this happens ?

Comment: By the way, I tried to put the full code, but there were no space to add it in the comment. However, if you can tell me the problem, with my last comment, maybe this fixes my issue.