# put figure at the bottom of the FIRST page

Tags: floats, subfloats, two-column, ieeetran, ieee-style

The problem is simple: how to force Latex to put the figure at the bottom of the first page.
I used [!hbt] but that makes the image at the top of the 2nd page.

```
\begin{figure*}[!thb]
 \centerline{
\includegraphics[width=1.7\columnwidth]{image.pdf} \hspace*{0.5cm}}
\caption{\label{fig:d} .   }
\end{figure*}
```

Note that the page is in a 2 column format. AND we have usually footnotes in the first page in ieee class, such as author affiliations. So How to put the figure at the bottom of the first page ABOVE the footnotes?

Comment: latex does not support `b` for `*` two column figures.

Comment: It is better to use `\centering` rather than `\centerline`. If you do use `\centerline` you need a `%` after the `{` or centering will be out by a space.

Comment: so how should i put it in the first page of a paper? no way?

Comment: The standard floating insert mechanism won't do it for you in 2 column mode, but you can place it there "by hand".  Just put the `\includegraphics` where you want it without using a `figure` environment and use `captionof` package to generate the caption properly.

Comment: that still doesnt work properly for 2 columns. I used this 
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.7\columnwidth]{pic}
  \captionof{figure}[One figure]{One figure; photo courtesy ...}

Comment: @ehsank -- you have to wrap your figure contents in a `minipage` that is the width of the full page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\def\a{One two three four five six seven eight nine ten. }
\def\b{\a\a\a\a\par\a Red green blue. \a\a\a Yellow. \a.\par}

\title{zzz}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\enlargethispage{-3.2cm}
\noindent\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-390){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{.75\textwidth}{2.5cm}%\includegraphics...
\captionof{figure}{zzzzz}
\end{minipage}}
\end{picture}%
\b\a\a\b\b\a\a\a\b
\enlargethispage{-3.2cm}
\b\b\b\a\a\b\b\a\a\a\b

\end{document}
```

Comment: "A River Runs Through It" :^)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes at least it makes a change from mock latin

Comment: Thanks a lot! however with ieee class it puts the image on the text. but anyway, it is so useful!

Comment: @ehsank yes you need to adjust the `(0,-390)`  and `\enlargethispage{-3.2cm}` by eye to position the figure. Not ideal but it gets the job done

Comment: hmmmph.  been done before -- see [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/579).  and there's an [article in the latest tugboat](https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111beet-banner.pdf) that demonstrates it.  (members only until november 2015.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton happy to vote close as dup (although probably I prefer this version:-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton actually I have extra powers, so voting not really needed:-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton it is still an open problem! with having footnotes in the first page (like author affiliation), the picture goes below the footnote which is not desirable.

Comment: @ehsank -- noted.  however, in a two-column page, made with the `[twocolumn]` option, not with `multicol`, footnotes are only the width of one column, so if there are no footnotes for the second column, you'd end up with a big blank at the bottom right.  that problem surely hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: This post really needs an explanation.

Comment: @mxbi the whole post was closed as duplicate 8 years ago, somewhat bizarre to ask for edits now.