# Figure at the bottom of page

Tags: floats, revtex

I am trying to put Fig 2 at the bottom of page 2 and Fig 3 at the bottom of page 3.

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx, float, placeins}
% \usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image.png}
   \caption{fig1}
\end{figure}

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\begin{figure*}[!b]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width = 15cm]{example-image.png}
   \caption{fig2}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image.png}
   \includegraphics[height = 4cm]{example-image.png}
   \caption{fig3}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

One solution I found here ([put figure at the bottom of the FIRST page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218199/put-figure-at-the-bottom-of-the-first-page)) but if I have a page full of text and then I am trying to put the figure at the bottom of the page, the text do not move to next page instead the text and figure get overlapped.

Comment: It would be easier if you could use `example-image` as the test image, as that is pre-installed for such tests (if that reproduces the problem)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I am now editing the question.

Comment: It appears revtex4-1 has a version of endfloat built in and all double floats are deferred. Even the [floatfix] option is implemented using \processdelayedfloats and will always take up an entire page.  In other words, revtex4-1 REALLY doesn't want you to do this!