# Displaying an image in two columns in a two column format

Tags: graphics, ieeetran, double-sided

I know that this question has been asked before. But I am having real trouble implementing the [before-mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document/30988) approaches into my document which is of IEEEtran class.

My code snippet is the following one:

```
\subsection{Testing the Image}

\begin{figure*}[h!]
        \centerline{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/Experiment.png}}}
        \caption{Experiment}
\end{figure*}

% TEXT HERE ... 
% TEXT HERE ...
% TEXT HERE ...
% TEXT HERE ...
```

But the resulting pdf has the image inserted in a **new page** and not above the %TEXT HERE segments as in the example.

How could I resolve this issue?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\begin{document}

    \author
    { 
        \IEEEauthorblockN{ Broxigar }

    }

    \title{Trying to spot this Error}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure*}[h!]
        \centering
        \centerline{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{eeee.png}}}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{fig}
    \end{figure*}
    \textbf{here???}
    \textbf{anybody????}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give a reference to "I know that this question has been asked before", furthermore can add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Okay, i did it....as you can see the  here??? and anybody???? added before the image and the image is in the new page.

Comment: The best solution is to move the figure* ahead one page, especially using IEEEtran.  You could use flowfram or an afterpage loop, but that would essentially move the figure* to the preamble.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I wish for the image to be at the point that its being inserted. If I add ```\lipsum``` after the image it works just fine. But when I try to add custom text, it doesn't

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/329777?r=SearchResults&s=6|11.8424#329777 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499556/order-of-figure-and-figure-figure-either-goes-to-next-page-or-order-reversed/499579?r=SearchResults&s=1|13.6704#499579

Comment: `figure*` does not support `b`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218199/put-figure-at-the-bottom-of-the-first-page#comment511638_218199 and I suppose it does not support `h` also. (I find full-width `h` figures weird, because  I never know where to continue reading...). You can see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107270/how-to-put-a-full-width-table-at-the-top-or-bottom-of-the-same-two-column-page-a

Comment: you can not use h with `figure*` and you have removed the option t so most likely you force the image to the end of the document

Comment: do you really want a figure with a caption or just insert an IEEE logo (can not run your document as it uses an image we don't have)

Comment: While thinking about it, I came up with a better solution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/531802#531802) but it won't work on the first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`figure*` does not support `h` (it's not clear what that would mean) so `[h!]` just has the effect of preventing `t` (top) or `p` (float page) so makes the float unable to be positioned anywhere until it is flushed out by `\clearpage` or `\end{document}`

double column floats always come at the earliest at the top of the next page,  so you can pot the `figure*` immediately after `\maketitle` and it will come as soon as possible, however there is not enough text in this example to fill the first page, so it comes at the end of the document.

If you really need the figure before **here?** then you need to force a pagebreak at that point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\begin{document}


    \author
    { 
        \IEEEauthorblockN{ Broxigar }

    }

    \title{Trying to spot this Error}
    \maketitle

    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \centerline{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image.png}}}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{fig}
    \end{figure*}

    \lipsum

\clearpage

    \textbf{here???}
    \textbf{anybody????}

\end{document}
```

But in most cases it would be better to avoid that, shown here with additional text

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\begin{document}


    \author
    { 
        \IEEEauthorblockN{ Broxigar }

    }

    \title{Trying to spot this Error}
    \maketitle

    \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \centerline{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image.png}}}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{fig}
    \end{figure*}

    \lipsum

    \textbf{here??? see Figure \ref {fig}}
    \textbf{anybody????}

    \lipsum

\end{document}
```