# Avoid table overlaying with another column in IEEEtran

Tags: tables, spacing

I am trying to create a table which is occupying end to end in the `IEEEtran` paper.
If the table comes in the first column, then the text on the right column overwrite the remaining columns of the table which extended into the second column

I want to make enough space on the right side so that my table appear end to end. Please help with this, thanks.

Comment: If you are getting overprinting then you are putting a table that is wider than the column into a column. There are loads of ways to make it smaller (and lots of answers on this site suggesting organizations for specific tables) but in general hard to say as you give no example. `\small` would make the table smaller but whether or not that makes it fit I can not guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David,basically I want it to expand in two columns, since I have multiple columns in the table. For it to be legible I want this to expand across the two columns and the text to continue beyond the table context . Here is the code:  AES&Delay(ps)&WNS&Req time(ps)&Frequency&Total Cap(pF)&Tot Power(mW)&Switch P(mW)&Int P(mW)&Leak P(mW)&Buff&Av length(um)&cells\\\hline
Original Case&379&+1&380&0.4&8.2&1.28&0.5789&0.5771&0.124&2940&2.2574&12972\\\hline\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}           Also I am using this format : \documentclass[12pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

Comment: \begin{table}
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
 \begin{tabularx}{2\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
AES&Delay(ps)&WNS&Req time(ps)&Frequency&Total Cap(pF)&Tot Power(mW)&Switch P(mW)&Int P(mW)&Leak P(mW)&Buff&Av length(um)&cells\\\hline
Original Case&379&+1&380&0.4&8.2&1.28&0.5789&0.5771&0.124&2940&2.2574&12972\\\hline
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}

Comment: Do you want to use `\begin{table*}` and `\end{table*}` to make a two-column table, as described in section X-D "Double Column Floats" of [the IEEEtran HOWTO](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107270/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following, maybe?

[image]

The code uses the `table*` environment since it spans both columns. (LaTeX will place such a float at the top of a page automatically.) The width of the `tabularx` environment is set to `\textwidth`, not `2\textwidth`. Note the use of the `X` column type for the first column and of the derived `C` column type for the remaining ones. I also suggest loading the `textcomp` package so that you can write `\textmu m` instead of `um`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx,textcomp}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\begin{table*} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|} \hline 
AES&Delay (ps)&WNS&Req time (ps)&Frequency&Total Cap (pF)&Tot Power (mW)
   &Switch P (mW)&Int P (mW)&Leak P (mW)&Buff&Av length (\textmu m)& cells\\
\hline 
Original Case &379&+1&380&0.4&8.2&1.28&0.5789&0.5771&0.124&2940&2.2574&12972\\
\hline 
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table*} 
\lipsum[1-20] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works, and it was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!