# IEEE specification for a two-column wide figure on the first page

Tags: positioning, two-column, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm trying to put a two-column wide figure on the first page of my manuscript to be submitted to IEEE conference. It seems that with `IEEEconf.cls` it doesn't allow me to do so. It always appears on the second page.

I'm wondering if it is somewhere mentioned that doing so is not permitted in IEEE.

Comment: It is generally not allowed to put `figure*` in the first page of two column document.

Comment: `IEEE.cls` does not exists... Are you using `IEEEconf.cls`?

Comment: yes sorry i meant ieeeconf.cls

Comment: As @HarishKumar says, in general this is not possible, and will likely be rejected by the journal. Simply put the figure on the next page. There exists a very dirty trick that allows it, but it is a likely reason for rejection. The body of the article has to start by the first section and not by a figure!

Comment: I mean putting it at the bottom of the first page, two-column wide. Even that is not allowed?

Comment: take a look at this: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/579).  it works, but whether or not it will be found acceptable is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HarishKumar says, in general this is not possible, and will likely be rejected by the journal. Simply put the figure on the next page. There exists a very dirty trick that allows it, but it is a likely reason for rejection. The body of the article has to start by the first section and not by a figure!

It is probably not mentioned in the manual since (1) the class simply never does it and (2) it is the standard, you never have a figure before the body of the document, so the only figures that can appear on the first page are at the bottom of either column, or at the top of the second column (but only the second column).

Ad your comment: There is a way how to put it at the bottom of the first page, but wide bottom figures are discouraged in twocolumn articles. And the trick is a dirty trick that involves manual measurements and seriously manual tweaks. (And if you post an MWE which shows your wide figure at the top of page 2, I can modify it to make it appear at the bottom of page 1.)