# Insert a figure in the first page of a one-page document

Tags: floats, positioning

I am trying to insert a figure in a one-page document in LaTeX, I am not sure about how to do it, though. All my attempts have created a new page, and what I am pursuing is to place the figure at the bottom of the page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\title{new document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=16cm]{scheme.jpg}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

What I am generating here is a two-page document, with the title in the first page and the figure in the middle of the second page.

Notice that the image does not belong to the title, it is a one-page report with a figure at the bottom with its caption and label, as usual.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/35864), [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/35864), [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/35864). Especially if you don't want captions (and a table of figures) I recommend the ["do not use a floating environment if you do not want it float" approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/35864) (of course captions are also possible there).

Comment: 1) don't use maketitle or 2) redefine it to allow figure in

Comment: Please read sections about float placement and two column figures and tables in `IEEEtran` documentation: "IEEE journals strongly favor the positioning of ﬂoats to the top of the page and rarely, if ever, use bottom ﬂoats." You can use package `stfloats` to force a `figure*` at bottom of page, but I think from second page. One column figures can be placed on top of second column in first page.

Comment: I've redefined _maketitle_ to put the figure as said @touhami.

Comment: But as @Ignasi pointed, I have the figure at the top, just before the title.

Comment: Do you need to use `IEEEtran`?

Comment: @Ignasi no I don't, it's not mandatory.

Comment: here's another approach that can put a figure at the bottom of a one-page document: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430).  it's a kludge, but it has withstood the test of time.

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't put the figure at the bottom, this has been a good approach:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\title{new document}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@maketitle{
\begin{figure}[H]
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\hsize}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=16cm]{scheme.jpg}
    \caption{scheme}
    \end{figure}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```