# Putting a diagram at the top/bottom in the two column document

Tags: diagrams, two-column

I am trying to put a graph on top or bottom of the page with text.
However when i use the code found on this website:

```
\begin{figure*}[!b]
 \centering
 {\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Graph-for-Malus}}
 \label{Fig. 5 Graph for Malus' Law verification}
 \caption{The graph shows the obtained results of the experiment plotted and the relationship between the intensity and the angle $v$ follows $cos^2(v)$ relationship very accurately.}
 \vspace{-13cm}
\end{figure*}
```

That results on the graph being put on the next page and not on the page i want it to go.
I tried a lot of different variations of the code and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: the standard latex figure* does not support `b` there are some packages that add this

Comment: see `stfloats` package.

Comment: Please add a picture with the desired result. Paint is totally okay for this.

Comment: Please always add a minimal working example not only a code snippet.

Comment: this might be helpful: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)