# Placing a figure at the bottom of the page in a two column document

Tags: graphics, floats, elsarticle

Can someone help me with placing the figure at the bottom (centered) of the document in sharelatex. Currently I am using:

```
\documentclass[final,authoryear,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}]
\userpackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\graphicspath{}
\begin{figure*}[b!]
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width= \textwidth,height= 12cm]{Study_area.PNG}}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:studysite}
  \end{center}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: by default two column figures at the bottom are not supported some packages add this eg `dblfloatfix` but I don't kno wif it's compatible with `elsarticle`

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Answer (score 4):

The `[b]` option for figure placement doesn't work in two-columns mode; by default page wide figures are placed at top of pages.  The `stfloats` package (from the `sttools` bundle) makes it available.

B.t.w., don't use the `center` environment for figures: it will add an unwanted vertical spacing in addition to the normal vertical spacing of figures.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
 \documentclass[final,authoryear,3p,times, twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frontmatter}
\lipsum[11]
   \begin{figure*}[b!]
   \centering
   \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax, height= 12cm]{Study_area.PNG}}
   \caption{} \label{fig:studysite}
   \end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{frontmatter}

   \end{document}
```

[image]