# tables into the page of Twocolumn

Tags: tables, two-column, sidewaystable

I want to collect different tables in one page. the page (it's ok by sidewaystable and `\smallskip`). But my main goal is into a page with `twocolumn`. How can I put the three tables in side way table side by side in the middle (sticking between them)?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second 
\smartqed  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[11]

\label{intro}
\begin{sidewaystable}\tiny
\caption{tableOne.}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{number}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{NF }} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ER (Test)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ER (training)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TT}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TR}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TY}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Pape}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{rize}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{color}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{good}}
  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{7 14 29 32}
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0475361} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,030550317} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10106} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9590} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{983} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,90703} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95124733} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,90919}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 7 8 14 29 31
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0332705} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,026415687} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10135} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9856} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{688} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,93475} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96627451} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,93559}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 10 16 22 28 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0239373} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,014870158} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10188} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9996} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95282} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97583834} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95324}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 13 17 27 29 35 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0200687} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,005863436} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10142} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10122} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{415} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96061} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,9799119} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96065}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 9 11 14 16 22 24 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0127666} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,011448813} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10154} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10261} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{264} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97492} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98729914} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97479}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 8 9 13 19 20 24 34 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00972} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,009079259} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10164} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10314} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{201} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98088} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99034999} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98075}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 8 10 13 14 16 17 24 31 32 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0086561} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,004606122} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10194} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10306} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{179} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98293} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99139051} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98284}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 17 18 19 24 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0079791} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,007181198} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10202} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10312} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{165} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98425} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99206311} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98417}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 2 6 7 8 9 13 14 16 18 19 21 22 31 32 34 35 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{19} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,007689} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,003372987} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10199} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10321} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{159} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98483} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99235614} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98474}
  \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{MEAN} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10 (average of 4 to 19)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0190693}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,012598664} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10165} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10120} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{394,3} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96256} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98074789} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96288}
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{NF: Number of Features; ER: Error Rate} &

  \\

\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:function 0}%

\smallskip
\caption{tabletwo}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{number}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{NF }} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ER (Test)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ER (training)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TT}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TR}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TY}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Pape}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{rize}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{color}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{good}}
  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{7 14 29 32}
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0475361} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,030550317} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10106} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9590} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{983} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,90703} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95124733} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,90919}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 7 8 14 29 31
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0332705} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,026415687} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10135} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9856} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{688} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,93475} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96627451} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,93559}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 10 16 22 28 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0239373} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,014870158} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10188} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9996} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95282} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97583834} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95324}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 13 17 27 29 35 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0200687} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,005863436} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10142} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10122} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{415} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96061} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,9799119} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96065}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 9 11 14 16 22 24 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0127666} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,011448813} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10154} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10261} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{264} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97492} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98729914} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97479}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 8 9 13 19 20 24 34 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00972} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,009079259} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10164} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10314} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{201} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98088} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99034999} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98075}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 8 10 13 14 16 17 24 31 32 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0086561} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,004606122} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10194} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10306} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{179} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98293} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99139051} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98284}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 17 18 19 24 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0079791} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,007181198} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10202} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10312} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{165} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98425} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99206311} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98417}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 2 6 7 8 9 13 14 16 18 19 21 22 31 32 34 35 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{19} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,007689} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,003372987} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10199} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10321} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{159} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98483} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99235614} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98474}
  \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{MEAN} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10 (average of 4 to 19)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0190693}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,012598664} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10165} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10120} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{394,3} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96256} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98074789} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96288}
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{NF: Number of Features; ER: Error Rate} &

\\

\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:function 1}%
\smallskip
\caption{tablethree}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{number}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{NF }} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ER (Test)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ER (training)}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TT}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TF}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TR}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{TY}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Pape}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{rize}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{color}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{good}}
  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{7 14 29 32}
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0475361} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,030550317} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10106} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9590} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{983} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,90703} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95124733} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,90919}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 7 8 14 29 31
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0332705} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,026415687} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10135} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9856} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{688} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,93475} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96627451} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,93559}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 10 16 22 28 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{8} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0239373} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,014870158} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10188} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9996} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{495} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95282} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97583834} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,95324}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 13 17 27 29 35 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{9} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0200687} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,005863436} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10142} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10122} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{415} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96061} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,9799119} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96065}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 9 11 14 16 22 24 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0127666} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,011448813} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10154} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10261} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{264} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97492} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98729914} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,97479}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 8 9 13 19 20 24 34 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,00972} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,009079259} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10164} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10314} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{201} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98088} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99034999} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98075}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 8 10 13 14 16 17 24 31 32 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{12} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0086561} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,004606122} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10194} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10306} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{179} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98293} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99139051} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98284}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 17 18 19 24 35 36
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0079791} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,007181198} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10202} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10312} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{165} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98425} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99206311} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98417}
  \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 2 6 7 8 9 13 14 16 18 19 21 22 31 32 34 35 36 37
} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{19} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,007689} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,003372987} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10199} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{10321} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{159} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98483} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,99235614} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98474}
  \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{MEAN} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10 (average of 4 to 19)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,0190693}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,012598664} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10165} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{10120} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{394,3} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96256} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,98074789} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,96288}
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{NF: Number of Features; ER: Error Rate} &

  \\

\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:function 3}%
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{RefJ}

Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)

\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: is this your question related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398520/collect-different-tables-into-the-page-of-twocolumn ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collect different tables into the page of twocolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398520/collect-different-tables-into-the-page-of-twocolumn)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How put three tables ("sidewaystable") side by side (sticking between them in the middlel) into page of twocolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398745/how-put-three-tables-sidewaystable-side-by-side-sticking-between-them-in-th)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107270/how-to-put-a-full-width-table-at-the-top-or-bottom-of-the-same-two-column-page-a)

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately your question is not very clear ... :-(

but inspection of your *mwe* shows may issues in table design, used packages etc. since i haven't document class `svjour3` i use standard `article` and `geometry` packages for emulating it. changes/additions in comparison to your *mwe* are in my *mwe* below indicated by `% <---`:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second
%\smartqed
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=25mm]{geometry}   % <---
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{array, booktabs,
            makecell,   % <---
            multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead[b]{#1}}}    % <---
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % <---
\usepackage{stfloats}   % <---

\usepackage{etoolbox}   % <---
\newcommand{\sbf}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
\robustify\sbf

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{table}[htb]      % <---
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{first table?}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                            *{4}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                            }
    \toprule
Context                 & \mc{Italian\\ (\%)}
                               & \mc{Bormino\\ (\%)}
                                      & \mc{Both\\ (\%)}
                                             & \mc{N/A\\ (\%)} \\
    \midrule
Mother                  & 24.3 & 59.5 & 16.2 & 0      \\
Parents to age 10       & 27.0 & 59.5 & 13.5 & 0      \\
Father                  & 29.7 & 56.8 & 10.8 & 2.7    \\
Grandfather             & 24.3 & 55.9 & 10.8 & 13.5   \\
Grandmother             & 24.3 & 54.1 & 13.5 & 8.1    \\
Brothers                & 21.6 & 46.0 & 10.8 & 21.6   \\
Swearing                & 27.0 & 40.5 & 16.2 & 16.2   \\
Sisters                 &  8.1 & 35.1 &  8.1 & 48.7   \\
Relatives               & 24.3 & 32.4 & 43.2 & 0      \\
Neighbors               & 24.3 & 27.0 & 46.0 & 2.7    \\
Partner                 & 32.4 & 24.3 & 27.0 & 16.2   \\
Son                     & 16.2 & 21.6 & 16.2 & 46.0   \\
Localities              & 29.7 & 21.6 & 48.7 & 0      \\
At Work                 & 32.4 & 21.6 & 43.2 & 2.7    \\
Colleagues              & 29.7 & 18.9 & 48.7 & 2.7    \\
Schoolmates             & 43.2 & 16.2 & 32.4 & 8.1    \\
Thinking                & 43.2 & 16.2 & 35.1 & 5.4    \\
Daughter                & 13.5 & 13.5 &  8.1 & 64.9   \\
Officials               & 67.6 & 13.5 & 18.9 & 0      \\
Praying                 & 40.5 & 10.8 & 16.2 & 32.4   \\
Counting/Mental math    & 62.2 &  8.1 & 29.7 & 0      \\
Teachers                & 73.0 &  8.1 &  5.4 & 13.5   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,
             detect-weight}
    \footnotesize
\caption{side way table}
  \label{tab:function 1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=2.0]
                S[table-format=1.7]
                S[table-format=1.8]
           *{2}{S[table-format=5.0]}
                S[table-format=1.0]
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=1.0]
                S[table-format=1.5]
                S[table-format=1.8]
                S[table-format=1.5]
                }

%                cc cc cc cc cc c}
    \midrule     % <---
\mc{number} & \mc{NF } & \mc{ER\\ (Test)} & \mc{ER\\ (training)} & \mc{TT}
    & \mc{TF} & \mc{TR} & \mc{TY} & \mc{Pape} & \mc{rize} & \mc{color} & \mc{good}  \\     % <---
    \midrule     % <---
\textbf{7 14 29 32}
    & \sbf 4   &
      0,0475361  &
      0,030550317  &
      10106  &
      9590  &
      0  &
      983  &
      1  &
      0,90703  &
      0,95124733  &
      0,90919
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 7 8 14 29 31}
  &
      6  &
      0,0332705  &
      0,026415687  &
      10135  &
      9856  &
      0  &
      688  &
      1  &
      0,93475  &
      0,96627451  &
      0,93559
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 10 16 22 28 35 36}
  &
      8  &
      0,0239373  &
      0,014870158  &
      10188  &
      9996  &
      0  &
      495  &
      1  &
      0,95282  &
      0,97583834  &
      0,95324
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 13 17 27 29 35 36 37}
  &
      9  &
      0,0200687  &
      0,005863436  &
      10142  &
      10122  &
      0  &
      415  &
      1  &
      0,96061  &
      0,9799119  &
      0,96065
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 9 11 14 16 22 24 36 37}
  &
      10  &
      0,0127666  &
      0,011448813  &
      10154  &
      10261  &
      0  &
      264  &
      1  &
      0,97492  &
      0,98729914  &
      0,97479
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 8 9 13 19 20 24 34 35 36}
  &
      11  &
      0,00972  &
      0,009079259  &
      10164  &
      10314  &
      0  &
      201  &
      1  &
      0,98088  &
      0,99034999  &
      0,98075
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{6 8 10 13 14 16 17 24 31 32 35 36}
  &
      12  &
      0,0086561  &
      0,004606122  &
      10194  &
      10306  &
      0  &
      179  &
      1  &
      0,98293  &
      0,99139051  &
      0,98284
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 17 18 19 24 35 36}
  &
      14  &
      0,0079791  &
      0,007181198  &
      10202  &
      10312  &
      0  &
      165  &
      1  &
      0,98425  &
      0,99206311  &
      0,98417
      \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{1 2 6 7 8 9 13 14 16 18 19 21 22 31 32 34 35 36 37}
  &
      19  &
      0,007689  &
      0,003372987  &
      10199  &
      10321  &
      0  &
      159  &
      1  &
      0,98483  &
      0,99235614  &
      0,98474
      \\
    \midrule
    MEAN  &
    10*   &
    0,0190693   &
    0,012598664  &
    10165  &
    10120  &
    0  &
    394,3  &
    1  &
    0,96256  &
    0,98074789  &
    0,96288
    \\
    \bottomrule     % <---
    \multicolumn{11}{c}{NF: Number of Features; ER: Error Rate; *: average of 4 to 19}
      \\

    \end{tabular*}%
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}

Your text comes here. Separate text sections with

\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.

\lipsum[11]

\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).

\lipsum[11]

\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[11]

% For one-column wide figures use
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example.eps}
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
%
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{two column tables or figures always appear on the top of the next page! exception is possible by use of package \texttt{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[11]

% For tables use
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule            % <---
first & second & third  \\
    \midrule            % <---
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
    \bottomrule         % <---
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[11]



\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{RefJ}

Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)

\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)

\end{thebibliography}
```

the first page generated by above *mwe* is:

[image]

**edit:**
apparently i didn't understood question well :-(. now i suspect that you like to have one page organized as "poster" which contain all tables in document (but not images). strange demand ...

[image]

however as show above image, this is possible, but not in one column (if you like that tables be readable ...). above solution has some limitations:

- page with tables should be inserted in the second column on page (if you do this in the first, the second will stay empty
- the image over two column can be inserted after first page text, otherwise arise spurious empty spaces
- as can you see, the first table i split into two parts which are set in parallel.
- added are two new packages: `pdflscape` and `afterpage`
- a lot of effort i put in off-topic problem of your tables (in both examples). i clean-up your code: now is far more clear, simpler and concise ...

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second
%\smartqed
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}   % <---
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{array, booktabs,
            makecell,       % <---
            multirow,
            threeparttable  % <---
            }
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead[b]{#1}}}    % <---
%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % <---
\usepackage{afterpage}  % <---
\usepackage{siunitx}    % <---
\usepackage{stfloats}   % <---

\usepackage{etoolbox}   % <---
\newcommand{\sbf}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
\robustify\sbf

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
Text with citations \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.

\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
\lipsum[3]


\paragraph{Paragraph headings}
Use paragraph headings as needed.
    \begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\afterpage{     % <---
\begin{landscape}
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,
             detect-weight}

    \centering
    \captionof{table}{first table?}
\begin{tabular*}{0.45\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                            *{4}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                                }
    \toprule
\mc{Context}            & \mc{Italian\\ (\%)}
                               & \mc{Bormino\\ (\%)}
                                      & \mc{Both\\ (\%)}
                                             & \mc{N/A\\ (\%)} \\
    \midrule
Mother                  & 24.3 & 59.5 & 16.2 & 0      \\
Parents to age 10       & 27.0 & 59.5 & 13.5 & 0      \\
Father                  & 29.7 & 56.8 & 10.8 & 2.7    \\
Grandfather             & 24.3 & 55.9 & 10.8 & 13.5   \\
Grandmother             & 24.3 & 54.1 & 13.5 & 8.1    \\
Brothers                & 21.6 & 46.0 & 10.8 & 21.6   \\
Swearing                & 27.0 & 40.5 & 16.2 & 16.2   \\
Sisters                 &  8.1 & 35.1 &  8.1 & 48.7   \\
Relatives               & 24.3 & 32.4 & 43.2 & 0      \\
Neighbors               & 24.3 & 27.0 & 46.0 & 2.7    \\
Partner                 & 32.4 & 24.3 & 27.0 & 16.2   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \quad
\begin{tabular*}{0.45\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                            l
                            *{4}{S[table-format=2.1]}
                            }
    \toprule
\mc{Context}            & \mc{Italian\\ (\%)}
                               & \mc{Bormino\\ (\%)}
                                      & \mc{Both\\ (\%)}
                                             & \mc{N/A\\ (\%)} \\
    \midrule
Son                     & 16.2 & 21.6 & 16.2 & 46.0   \\
Localities              & 29.7 & 21.6 & 48.7 & 0      \\
At Work                 & 32.4 & 21.6 & 43.2 & 2.7    \\
Colleagues              & 29.7 & 18.9 & 48.7 & 2.7    \\
Schoolmates             & 43.2 & 16.2 & 32.4 & 8.1    \\
Thinking                & 43.2 & 16.2 & 35.1 & 5.4    \\
Daughter                & 13.5 & 13.5 &  8.1 & 64.9   \\
Officials               & 67.6 & 13.5 & 18.9 & 0      \\
Praying                 & 40.5 & 10.8 & 16.2 & 32.4   \\
Counting/Mental math    & 62.2 &  8.1 & 29.7 & 0      \\
Teachers                & 73.0 &  8.1 &  5.4 & 13.5   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

    \medskip
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{side way table}
  \label{tab:function 1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                S[table-format=2.0]
                S[table-format=1.7]
                S[table-format=1.9]
           *{2}{S[table-format=5.0]}
                S[table-format=1.0]
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=1.0]
                S[table-format=1.5]
                S[table-format=1.8]
                S[table-format=1.5]
                }
    \midrule     % <---
\mc{number} & \mc{NF\tnote{a}}
            & \mc{ER\tnote{b}\\ (Test)}
            & \mc{ER\tnote{b}\\ (training)}
            & \mc{TT\tnote{c}}
            & \mc{TF\tnote{d}}
            & \mc{TR\tnote{e}}
            & \mc{TY\tnote{f}}
            & \mc{Pape} & \mc{rize} & \mc{color} & \mc{good}  \\     % <---
    \midrule     % <---
\textbf{7 14 29 32}
        & \sbf 4
        & 0,0475361
        & 0,030550317
        & 10106
        & 9590
        & 0
        & 983
        & 1
        & 0,90703
        & 0,95124733
        & 0,90919           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 7 8 14 29 31}
        & 6
        & 0,0332705
        & 0,026415687
        & 10135
        & 9856
        & 0
        & 688
        & 1
        & 0,93475
        & 0,96627451
        & 0,93559           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 10 16 22 28 35 36}
        & 8
        & 0,0239373
        & 0,014870158
        & 10188
        & 9996
        & 0
        & 495
        & 1
        & 0,95282
        & 0,97583834
        & 0,95324           \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 13 17 27 29 35 36 37}
        & 9
        & 0,0200687
        & 0,005863436
        & 10142
        & 10122
        & 0
        & 415
        & 1
        & 0,96061
        & 0,9799119
        & 0,96065           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 9 11 14 16 22 24 36 37}
        & 10
        & 0,0127666
        & 0,011448813
        & 10154
        & 10261
        & 0
        & 264
        & 1
        & 0,97492
        & 0,98729914
        & 0,97479           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 7 8 9 13 19 20 24 34 35 36}
        & 11
        & 0,00972
        & 0,009079259
        & 10164
        & 10314
        & 0
        & 201
        & 1
        & 0,98088
        & 0,99034999
        & 0,98075           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{6 8 10 13 14 16 17 24 31 32 35 36}
        & 12
        & 0,0086561
        & 0,004606122
        & 10194
        & 10306
        & 0
        & 179
        & 1
        & 0,98293
        & 0,99139051
        & 0,98284           \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{2 6 7 8 9 11 13 14 17 18 19 24 35 36}
        & 14
        & 0,0079791
        & 0,007181198
        & 10202
        & 10312
        & 0
        & 165
        & 1
        & 0,98425
        & 0,99206311
        & 0,98417           \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{1 2 6 7 8 9 13 14 16 18 19 21 22 31 32 34 35 36 37}
        & 19
        & 0,007689
        & 0,003372987
        & 10199
        & 10321
        & 0
        & 159
        & 1
        & 0,98483
        & 0,99235614
        & 0,98474           \\
    \midrule
MEAN    & 10\tnote{*}
        & 0,0190693
        & 0,012598664
        & 10165
        & 10120
        & 0
        & 394,3
        & 1
        & 0,96256
        & 0,98074789
        & 0,96288           \\
    \bottomrule     % <---
    \end{tabular*}%
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize
    \item[a] NF: Number of Features;
    \item[b] ER: Error Rate;
    \item[d] TT: \dots;
    \item[e] TF: \dots;
    \item[f] TR: \dots;
    \item[g] TY: \dots;
    \item[*] average of 4 to 19.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}

    \medskip
\captionof{table}{third table}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabular}{l @{\hskip 6pt} l @{\hskip 6pt} l}
    \toprule            % <---
first & second & third  \\
    \midrule            % <---
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
    \bottomrule         % <---
\end{tabular}

\end{landscape}
        } % end of afterpage
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with

\lipsum[5]

% For one-column wide figures use
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example.eps}
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-7]
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{two column tables or figures always appear on the top of the next page! exception is possible by use of package \texttt{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[8]

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{RefJ}
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)

\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```