# Put a table at the bottom of a conference paper

Tags: tables, positioning

I meet a problem of putting a table at the bottom of a conference paper. Because I want this table to be very **small** so I use the following way (I learned here before):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{IEEEconf} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[b]
\footnotesize
\hrulefill
\begin{table}
\caption{An Example of a Table}
\label{table_example}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
\hline
One & Two\\
\hline
Three & Four\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{figure*}  
\end{document}
```

However, latex shows:

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

How do I fix it? What does that mean?  Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to make your fragment compilable. At least in the standard classes, `b` is impossible with `figure*` in a two-column environment. LaTeX can place such floats only at the top of a page (`t`) or on a float page (`p`). If you think you learnt this here before, can you please provide a link? I always annotate my code with comments giving sources, partly for purposes of proper attribution and partly so I can easily find such resources again. Hopefully, you either do this or can turn it up in a search. I ask because I suppose you must not have learnt quite this here.

Comment: I get `ieeeconf.cls` not found. You mean `IEEEconf`?

Comment: @cfr yes! https://cdc2018.ieeecss.org/author_info.php

Comment: related, possible duplicate: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}[b]
\footnotesize
\hrulefill
\caption{An Example of a Table}
\label{table_example}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
\hline
One & Two\\
\hline
Three & Four\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: Don't know if it is what you need, because I didn't understood the way you tried to use `table` inside `figure`

Comment: Yes, but probably the OP is using `figure*` because the document is formatted two-column, and this will not work there.

Comment: It seems that it does not make any change if I delete \footnotesize. However, I I want to control the size of it? I mean if I want everything at the bottom of the page to be very small? (That is why I use figure)

Comment: I had not the documentclass. I tested using \tiny and works... Do you want to control caption size too?.Also See @cfr's comment. I am working on the real MWE now

Comment: @Denny You can't put it at the bottom if it is a float with the class settings you're using because double-column floats cannot use `b`.

Comment: @Denny my code doesn't really work with your documentclass (I could not do it and @cfr is right). Also `conference` seems to be an invalid option in my tests...

Answer (score 2):

With the `ieeeconf` class, you can obtain what you want with the `stfloats` package, from the `sttools` bundle, with one exception:  the table can't appear at the bottom of the first page.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{stfloats, caption}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{table*}[b]
\hrulefill
\footnotesize\centering
\caption{An Example of a Table}
\label{table_example}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
\hline
One & Two\\
\hline
Three & Four\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]