# Two column figures with figure* - bottom on same page - figure numbering wrong

Tags: floats, two-column, article

So in order to have a full width figure on the bottom on the same page we have to move the figure to the previous page. But given that we have a figure before this, which is also referenced before it, we have to move to this too in order to keep the numbering of the figures in order. 
However, the figure we took with us for may now appear on previous page instead of at the location we wanted it.

Anyway to get around this?

I tried the `\afterpage{}` which put the figure on right page but the numbering is still wrong.

Code example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{OneColumnFigure.png}
    \caption{OneColumnFigure}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[b!]
    \includegraphics{TwoColumnFigure.png}
    \caption{TwoColumnFigure}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

This will make our OneColumnFigure appear on the same page on the desired location, but our TwoColumnFigure will appear on the next page on the bottom which is not where we want it:

[image: 1]

If we move TwoColumnFigure to previous page, the layout will be correct but the figure numbering wrong:

[image: 2]

And if we move both figures to the previous page, the numbering will be correct but the layout wrong:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Answer from: [Order of figure and figure* - figure* either goes to next page or order reversed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499556/order-of-figure-and-figure-figure-either-goes-to-next-page-or-order-reversed)

*I was able to solve this problem by manipulating the counter. I embedded `\setcounter{figure}{#}` into the `figure` and `figure*`. The count reordered the figure numbering and preserves the placement.*

Comment: What is than your problem, if you now say that manually numbering of figures solve your problem?

Comment: Nothing. It is solved by manually numbering the figures. Your solution does not work as intended. I cannot accept my own answer until tomorrow which is why this is not closed yet.

Comment: Well, than your question is duplicate. See @ John Kormylo comment.