# How to fix a footer minipage at the bottom of a page without using of e.g. "fancyhdr"?

Tags: tex-core

I've to fix a footer minipage on one page at the bottom of that page without using of e.g. `fancyhdr` so that the floating text is breaking into new page when that footer is reached. How to do that? Many thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** (2021-09-25)

The volume of the beginning text at page 1 is not static. It is dynamically given by another program. It can be 130 words long but also 1,000 or so. So a `{figure}[b]` at page 1 is no option here because the text may move this figure to page 2 when the volume of the text is big enough.

[image]

The text is floating into new page because the minipage is reached but the minipage keeps at this position:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate your question to be more clear? Please...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the `fancyhdr` package?

Comment: @leandriis: I've a quite simple TeX installation without `fancyhdr` and I can't install additional packages.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't really want a footer, you just want a minipage at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bottom float. THIS IS AN EDITED VERSION OF MY ORIGINAL ANSWER

```
% botprob.tex  SE 616534

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setlength{\textheight}{0.4\textheight}

%%% EDITED RESPONSE
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
\fbox{At the bottom of the page.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}

% ORIGINAL RESPONSE

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[b]
\fbox{At the bottom of the page.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}

\begin{figure}
A FIGURE.
\caption{A fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but e.g. `\begin{document}\lipsum[1-5]\begin{figure}[b]...` moves the figure to page 2. So the figure isn't fixed at page 1.

Comment: Also, this requires the figure queue to be empty, otherwise it will wait for its turn.

Comment: @Toru I have revised my answer, resolving your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit overkill, but easy to implement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{Message}{b}{lom}% \message already used

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{Message} 
  Hello World!
\end{Message}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

---

This version takes more work but gives more control over the spacing (`\textfloatsep`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement=b,fileext=lom]{floatmsg}

\newsavebox{\messagebox}
\newenvironment{Message}{\floatmsg\vskip-\textfloatsep
  \begin{lrbox}{\messagebox}\minipage{\dimexpr \linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}%
{\endminipage\end{lrbox}\fbox{\box\messagebox}\endfloatmsg}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{Message} 
  Hello World!
\end{Message}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `\begin{document}\lipsum[1-5]\begin{Message}...` moves the message to page 2. So the message isn't fixed at page 1. See my update.

Comment: If you wait until page 2 to create it, there is no way to put it on page 1.  Do you want to specify the page number and create it in the preamble?  (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506766/pin-figure-to-page-and-column-in-a-2-column-document)