# Figure* causing placement of figure on wrong page when using two column latex

Tags: positioning

I'm adding two figures to my latex document which is two column format, making them cover both columns like below. However, this moves them to the second and third pages respectively even if I add this text on the very first page. This is strange to read since they are referenced on the first page. Is there a way to control where the figures get placed?

```
\begin{figure*}[h!]
\vskip 0.2in
\begin{center}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pps3steps.png}}
\caption{Pre-provisioning involves 3 high-level steps.}
\label{fig:pps3steps}
\end{center}
\vskip -0.2in
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Makes sense. Will do it shortly. Thanks!

Comment: This question deals with the same problem although with `table*`: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)  (All floats are equivalent in the important respects.)

Comment: `figure*` has no `h` argument so `\begin{figure*}[h!]`  specifies a figure with **no legal place that it may be positioned** so it will go to the end of the document or `\clearpage`.

Comment: unrelated but `\centerline` and `\vskip` are not latex commands and shouldn't be used in latex documents (`\centerline` here is doing nothing in any case)

Comment: also note that `figure*` always comes at the earliest on the page after it appears in the source

Comment: You should start by reading [Frank Mittelbach's article](https://www.latex-project.org/publications), then remove all placement directives from the figure environments, and see how LaTeX handle the placement. This you should postpone until you have finished writing your document, i.e. after the second proof reading. Focus on the creative writing, not where a figure ends up under the drafting cycles. That a waste of time.