# Use whole page width in twocolumn document

Tags: two-column, multicolumn, width, page

I am working with my document class set as `[twocolumn]{article}` and all is working well however I would like to know if it is possible to use the whole page witdth for text within the document.

I have tried using `\centerline` and `center` to try and nudge the text however they only centre to the middle of the column (as expected).

I also cannot use `multcols` so I am stuck to whatever is possible with `twocolumn`.

[image: what I need]

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\AfterEndEnvironment{strip}{\leavevmode}

% Allow me to use \newpage to swap sides.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
  \newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Fare}}
\begin{description}
\item io faccio
\item tu fai
\item lui/lei fa
\item noi facciamo
\item voi fate
\item loro fanno
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Andare}}
\begin{description}
\item io vado
\item tu vai
\item lui/lei va
\item noi andiamo
\item voi andate
\item loro vanno
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Potere}}
\begin{description}
\item io posso
\item tu puoi
\item lui/lei può
\item noi possiamo
\item voi potete
\item loro possono
\end{description}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Leggere}}
\begin{description}
\item io leggo
\item tu leggi
\item lui/lei legge
\item noi leggiamo
\item voi leggete
\item loro leggono
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Scrivere}}
\begin{description}
\item io scrivo
\item tu scrivi
\item lui/lei scrive
\item noi scriviamo
\item voi scrivete
\item loro scrivono
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Parlare}}
\begin{description}
\item io parlo
\item tu parli
\item lui/lei parla
\item noi parliamo
\item voi parlete
\item loro parlano
\end{description}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Sapere}}
\begin{description}
\item io so
\item tu sai
\item lui/lei sa
\item noi sappiamo
\item voi sapete
\item loro sanno
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Conoscere}}
\begin{description}
\item io conosco
\item tu conosci
\item lui/lei conosce
\item noi conosciamo
\item voi conoscete
\item loro conoscono
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Pensare}}
\begin{description}
\item io penso
\item tu pensi
\item lui/lei pensa
\item noi pensiamo
\item voi pensate
\item loro pensano
\end{description}
\end{minipage}

\newpage

\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Capire}}
\begin{description}
\item io capisco
\item tu capisci
\item lui/lei capisce
\item noi capiamo
\item voi capite
\item loro capiscono
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.165\textwidth}
\textsc{\textbf{Studiare}}
\begin{description}
\item io studio
\item tu studi
\item lui/lei studia
\item noi studiamo
\item voi studiate
\item loro studiano
\end{description}
\end{minipage}

% Adding a strip environment here breaks the layout.
% This is where I want my full-page text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: @Bernard Interesting! Any idea how to get it to work with `minipage` ?

Comment: More specifically, with `minipages` at the end of a page instead of the top.

Comment: I don't understand.?? You want two minipages side by side in this environment?

Comment: @Bernard I already do, and am now using `\newpage` to swap sides of the page. I'll add my code.

Comment: Please do (a compilable code, so I can understand).

Comment: @Bernard It has been added. Simply adding a `strip` at the comment position will break the layout however your suggestion *does* work perfectly at the top of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101724/discussion-between-bernard-and-finn-rayment).

Comment: There's a gruesome hack that should work, explained in [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh! That was actually _surprisingly_ easy! I just added in your `minipage` and it works perfectly. Thank you! (I don't know how you feel about writing that out as an answer but I'd be happy to accept it)

Comment: @FinnRayment -- Since you've found that this suggestion works, I'm happy, but the convention of this site is to close the newer question as a duplicate.  So that's what I'll vote for.  (But you've been warned -- it's really a wicked hack, and not looked on favorably by LaTeX purists.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton That is fair. I'll flag it too (if that is even a thing). Thankfully I'm not trying to please the LaTeX gods :)