# Table that starts immediately after text finishes from the same page in a two column document

Tags: multicolumn

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\input{hicss51-packages.tex} %its basically twocolumn document class
\newcommand{\sansserifformat}[1]{\fontfamily{cmss}{ #1}}%
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs}
```

`\begin{table*}`

```
\begin{tabular} {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.9cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.9cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.9cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.9cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.9cm}}

................
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

I have a table. But it starts with the new page in a two column document environment. I want that table immediately after my text just like the following figure. Not in a new page. Which code I need to implement here just to make the text and remaining table in a single page.

[image]

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you currently produce your documents. Do you use the `multicol` package or a `twocolumn` documentclass?

Comment: [Put a table* at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3527/134144) could be interesting.

Comment: Or put your table in a `strip` environment (`cuted` packahe).

Comment: @leandriis Sorry for your confusion. I have added some codes on there. Its a two column document class. 

I want that table just after my text not from a new page.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your solution. Actually its working. But my table is kind of big. I want it to span through 2 pages. When I am applying strip environment rest of my table is not going to the next page. Any solution please!!!

Comment: You can use `longtable`, or `xltabular`,  which combines  `tabularx`and `longtable`. If I remember well, it works inside `strip`.

Comment: I have the same question. I want to stick my long table in the line after two column text article.