# How to make a figure span two columns in an acmart document

Tags: acmart

I am trying to make a figure span both columns in an acmart document. I have tried using figure* but that simply makes the figure disappear from the document. Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{generated_music_example.eps} 
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have also tried using `\onecolumn` but it puts the figure on a new page on its own (without any text around it despite there being enough space for it).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's very difficult to put a full-width float on the first page of any article.  Here are two existing questions dealing with full-width figures: [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430) and [Put a table* at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution thanks to barbara beeton. The accepted answer in [Put a table* at the bottom of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/put-a-table-at-the-bottom-of-a-page) mentions the use of the stfloats package with a figure placement of [bp]. This ended up working for me.